# How can I adjust the x-axis "Date" labels of the graph using the Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, graph-visualization

**1. Problem**
I wanted to know the change in transaction prices over time, so I made a scatter plot graph.
The big picture was drawn roughly, but the minor issue was not solved. It is the display interval of the x-axis label.
The results I made for the first time and the part of code for them are as follows.
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df = df.loc[df['계약면적(㎡)'] > 33]

# Data in the form of 202109 was made into 2021-09-01 
# and then make date data in the form of 202109 using dt.strftime ('%Y%m').

df['계약년월'] = df['계약년월'].astype(str)
df['계약년월'] = df['계약년월'].str[0:4] + '-' + df['계약년월'].str[4:6] + '-01'

df['계약년월'] = pd.to_datetime(df['계약년월'])
df['계약년월'] = df['계약년월'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')

# Graph

plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))

ax = plt.gca()

yticks = [100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000]
ylabels = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
plt.yticks(yticks, labels = ylabels)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

plt.scatter(df['계약년월'], df['면적당 금액(원)'])
plt.xlabel('계약년월')
plt.ylabel('면적당 금액(원/㎡)')

plt.savefig('Graph.jpg')
```

As you can see, the label of xticks is displayed as 201101 201308 201512 201807 202101.
**I would like to mark this every end of each year in the way 20111212 201312 201412 201521 201612 201712 201812 201912 202012 and so on.**

**2. What I've tried**
Since yticks were easily changed at my disposal, I tried applying the same method to xticks. The code for it is as follows.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))

ax = plt.gca()

yticks = [100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000]
ylabels = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
plt.yticks(yticks, labels = ylabels)

# xticks I want to show.
xticks = ['201112', '201212', '201312', '201412', '201512', '201612', '201712', '201812', '201912', '202012']

# For the above list, it was converted into date data in the form of '%Y%m'.

xticks = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m') for x in xticks]

# xlabels displayed in the graph

xlabels = ['2011y-end', '2012y-end', '2013y-end', '2014y-end', '2015y-end', '2016y-end', '2017y-end', '2018y-end', '2019y-end', '2020y-end']

plt.xticks(xticks, labels = xticks)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=None, interval=2, tz=None))

plt.scatter(df['계약년월'], df['면적당 금액(원)'])
plt.xlabel('계약년월')
plt.ylabel('면적당 금액(원/㎡)')

plt.savefig('Graph.jpg')
```

However, the results were disastrous.
[image]
Perhaps there was a problem in the process of touching the tick, and this result came after 201212 followed by 201213 instead of 201301.

I was worried about this, so I used strftime and strptime to convert both the 'data' and 'ticks list' into date form('%Y%m'), but I wonder why it didn't apply as I intended.

Please understand if there is an inefficient code due to be not used to Python yet, and I would appreciate it if you could let me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
plt.xlim(datetime.datetime(2011,12),datetime.datetime(2020,12))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b\n%Y'))
```

You can set x-axis major formatted according to your wish, here I used `%d` for the day, `%b` for month, `\n` for new line and `%Y` represents year.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).